# Wrong vsnprintf output

Tags: c++, printf, variadic-functions

I have the following functions:

```
void raiseError(const char *msg, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, msg); // use variable arg list

    int size = vsnprintf(nullptr, 0, msg, ap);
    std::vector<char> s(size+1, 0);
    vsnprintf(s.data(), size, msg, ap);
    va_end(ap);
    errorString = std::string(s.data()));
}
```

When I call

```
raiseError("File not found in <%s> : <%s>", "a", "b" );
```

The first vsnprintf call (which computes the final string size) returns the correct value of 27. But the final string is:

"File not found in <**A*> :"

Where the '*' characters are random across program launches.

Also, the program works in MinGW, the issue is only seen with linux gcc.

What is wrong in my code?

Comment: Just speculating - is it legal to use `ap` twice? You might need to `va_end()` after the first call to `vsnprintf()` and `va_start()` again before the next.

Comment: This is what I was figuring... But since all input arguments are read only, why not? I will check out...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use ap more than once.  Look into using va_copy.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I just read the va_list reference. Surprisingly, this worked well in MinGW, maybe they iterate back to the first argument after the last one

Comment: Programs that have undefined behavior are not "working well".  Change compiler options or some other factor, and you may no longer have a "working" program.

Comment: My comment was not about "UB code is working well in MinGW, why is it not working with linux gcc?" but about "stdlib source should be nearly the same between linux gcc and mingw gcc for these string functions, so I wonder why such a difference was introduced". MinGW clearly repeats the argument list when iterating twice.